# how to find control from string vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working on vb.net window application where i have to find Control in window form by string name. For that i used the following code:-

```
Dim lbl As New Label
Dim st As String

st = "lblFeeder" + i.ToString()
lbl = CType(Me.Controls(st), Label)
lbl.Text = dt.Rows(37)("AnaTagValue")
```

But when the program runs it gives a error

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

at the postion

```
"lbl.Text = dt.Rows(37)("AnaTagValue")"
```

When i debug it i Found "Nothing" at the position 
     "lbl = CType(Me.Controls(st), Label)"

How can I solve this?

Comment: You don't check if you have found the control or not. Remember, controls can be contained in controls container other than the form itself (GroupBoxes, panels)

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: If you get a Nothing then there is no control with that name in the Form (Me) controls collection. If you are sure that a control with that name exists then it is not inside the form controls collection but probably inside a GroupBox or Panel or some other controls container. You should find the correct container and use its collection for reference the label

Comment: This control is present inside a form panel which is also inside another panel.

Comment: then _Me.Panel1Name.Panel2Name.Controls_ for the first parameter of CType

Comment: @Steve it really works fine for me. Thanks a lot.